# Access PHP variables in HTML of same page

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

If I have a page that has a link `<a href='edit_info.php?id=1001'>1001</a>` and on the page edit_info.php I would like to use the id to make a query to a database, say

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $_GET['id']`

Now I want to fill a bunch of text fields with the results. Must I do this all in the same php

(`'<?php //place all fields in an echo here ?>`)

Or is there a way I can make the query and then in html pull the data from the query?

ex.

```
<?php //query and results here ?>

<html>
  <body>
   all my input fields w/ data here
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd be setting the input fields with the values from the query.

Example:

```
<input type="textbox" name="input_name" value="<?php print $valuefromquery; ?>">
```

And do for each of the results you'd like to display.
Also use [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) /[`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) to query the database.

Comment: I always use mysqli but I have coded everything I am doing so far procedurally so i haven't used PDO.

Comment: @user2690363 All good :) I apologise for assuming you would've done it in mysql_* because you put the `$_GET['id']` straight into the query.

Comment: @Phil Thats left up to the person to do, I answered the question as to how he would have the values display in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it all in one `php` file.

You can do the example you made. You can open `<?php` and close `?>` php code in between your `html` or `javascript`. Just close and escape properly.

**AND** take note of [**XSS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting%E2%80%8E)

**AND AND** you might also find php [**include**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) useful. It helps when you are reusing php code . . like a dynamic personalized header maybe?

Comment: you mean `mysqli_real_escape_string()`? I am using. Am also using a header through include, or `require_once()` whichever shoe fits

Comment: not real escape string. thats for db queries. Im talking about http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php BTW you should learn prepared statements. MySQLi has them. It has a learning curve but once you get it right you would be more confident on your db queries.

Comment: So basically any time you're passing certain characters through the URL via GET you should use the special characters function so the link translates those special characters properly. Correct?